# NET-SNMP Trap processing with python

Tags: pysnmp, snmp-trap

Is there any python modules for working with received NET-SNMP traps? I am not looking for the whole process of capturing SNMP trap with something like pysnmp, but just processing. Formatting values and maybe creating a json from received notification.

Answer (score 1):

Your original question was about pysnmp so I'm answering that. ;-)

A lot depends on what you mean by *processing*. With pysnmp you can build an app from two independent parts -- the capturing part and the formatting part.

For capturing you can take [this script](http://pysnmp.sourceforge.net/examples/v3arch/asyncore/manager/ntfrcv/transport-tweaks.html#serving-multiple-network-interfaces) which gives you SNMP variable-bindings that come in the TRAP message. Once you get the var-bindings you can run them through the [MIB lookup](http://pysnmp.sourceforge.net/examples/smi/manager/browsing-mib-tree.html#pdu-var-binds-to-mib-objects) part which would produce human-friendly names for OIDs and prettily formatted values.

This should work out of the box except that for the MIB lookup to succeed you need to know and explicitly pre-load MIBs your agents implement (e.g. `.loadModules()` call).

Transforming prettified OID-values into JSON seems trivial with Python's built-in `json.dumps()`.

Comment: Thanks for the tips!